# NHibernate and SQL Server Temporal Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, temporal-tables

I am using Fluent NHibernate to query data stored in a [SQL Server temporal table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16). All I really want to do is to run a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] for system_time as of '2022-12-28T21:00:00.0000000' where ...
```

Via NHibernate. It doesn't seem like there's any way built in to NHibernate that can run that query. I can run queries such as below but that only hits the current table, and not the history table.

```
session.QueryOver<MyDTO>().Where(x => x.TemporalPeriodStart > ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute native SQL queries (and return non managed entities).
The query needs to specify:

- Query String
- A Result transformer

Example:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] for system_time as of '2022-12-28T21:00:00.0000000' where...")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(CustomObject)))
```

Worth noting that the custom IResultTransformer should override "Equals" and "GetHashCode", otherwise a memory leak is possible since query translation won't be cached.

You can also use Named SQL query, which can be defined in the mapping document and called in the same way as a named HQL query...